# MapReduce program Performance testing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

how can we check which map is running slow in mapreduce program? During the job and afte completing the job?

What are the parameters needs to be checked for MapReduce performance testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very broad, but still trying to address to an extent..

1) While Job is running you can see in application master

2) After job completed you can see in the job history

Please see job-tracker and task tracker documentation of map-reduce.

Parameters for performance testing is very broad term. There are some default testcases which will ship with distribution

In general, we an see how much time job(including map and reduce phases) is taking and how much time each map is taking using the aforementioned trackers.

Apart from that you can also see the number of records(inputsplit) for each mapper. and various other parameters from the sample screen shot below[image: HisotoryAfterJobCompleted]

after monitoring job, we can come to conclusion and you can fine tune that. Please   see some of the [tips](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/12/7-tips-for-improving-mapreduce-performance/)